# Read JSON Data Have Token With PHP

Tags: php, json, response

How can I read a JSON data response using php?

This is Code :

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://montanaflynn-spellcheck.p.mashape.com/check/?text=This+sentnce+has+some+probblems.",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "MY X-Mashape-Key",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);
```

and give me this json data :

```
{
  "original": "This sentnce has some probblems.",
  "suggestion": "This sentence has some problems.",
   and ...
}
```

I want to return "`suggestion`" in a url with `$`

this is an example :

```
$user_id = '123456789'
$mytext = '?' // I WANT RETURN "suggestion" HERE !

$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id.'&text='.$mytext
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: give us an example of the input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json_decode().

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You just need to do:

```
$response = json_decode($response,1);
echo $response['suggestion'];
```

Setting the second parameter of json_decode() to 1 (true) will return an associative array of the JSON data.

If you want to include it in a URL using your code example:

```
$user_id = '123456789'
$json = json_decode($response,1);
$mytext = $json['suggestion'];

$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id.'&text='.$mytext
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Thank you Worked !

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to convert json_response to array.Add second parameter of 'true' to make it an array that you should be familiar with.

Access suggestion variable by specifying it.

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://montanaflynn-spellcheck.p.mashape.com/check/?text=This+sentnce+has+some+probblems.",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "MY X-Mashape-Key",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);
$data=json_decode($response,true);
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id.'&text='.$data['suggestion'];
echo $url;
```

Comment: thank you for answer How can i return it in a url with $